# How do I transfer data from on-premise hadoop cluster to AWS S3 using Oozie? (Oozie is installed on on-premise cloudera cluster)

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, cloudera, oozie

How do I transfer data from the on-premise Hadoop cluster to AWS S3 using Oozie? (Oozie is installed on on-premise Cloudera cluster)

Comment: Oozie is workflow scheduler, not an application that transfers data.

Comment: @tk421 So? It can schedule the copy

Comment: Please show some research in your questions when posting. https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/cdh_admin_distcp_data_cluster_migrate.html#distcp_and_s3

Comment: Were you able to do it? What is the idea behind doing this - is it for backup or you want to move the data to s3 for Hive/Spark on s3 and/or run EMR(Hadoop on AWS) cluster to access this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Java program for this, AWS has provided put method by which we can upload the data from on premises to AWS s3 . then schedule  this , by using Oozie. Remember Oozie is not a program that can upload data into AWS, it is just a scheduled.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to use oozie, use DistCP and check your setup:
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html

```
 hadoop distcp -Dhadoop.security.credential.provider.path=jceks://hdfs/aws/aws.jceks /test s3a://kartik-test/
```

The standard for moving data in and out of Hadoop is [Apache NiFi](https://nifi.apache.org)

Apache NiFi supports powerful and scalable directed graphs of data routing, transformation, and system mediation logic. Some of the high-level capabilities and objectives of Apache NiFi include:

> -Web-based user interface
>
> -Seamless experience between design, control, feedback, and monitoring
>
> -Highly configurable
>
> -Loss tolerant vs guaranteed delivery
>
> -Low latency vs high throughput
>
> -Dynamic prioritization
>
> -Flow can be modified at runtime
>
> -Back pressure
>
> -Data Provenance
>
> -Track dataflow from beginning to end
>
> -Designed for extension
>
> -Build your own processors and more
>
> -Enables rapid development and effective testing
>
> -Secure
>
> -SSL, SSH, HTTPS, encrypted content, etc...
>
> -Multi-tenant authorization and internal authorization/policy management

Answer (score 0):

With temporary credentials (e.g for testing):

```
   <action name="distcp">
      <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.2">
          <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
          <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
          <configuration>
              <property>
                  <name>fs.s3a.aws.credentials.provider</name>
                  <value>${distCpCredentialsProvider}</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
                  <value>${aws_access_key}</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
                  <value>${aws_secret_key}</value>
              </property>
              <property>
                  <name>fs.s3a.session.token</name>
                  <value>${aws_session_token}</value>
              </property>
          </configuration>
          <arg>hdfs:${hdfsBasePath}</arg>
          <arg>s3a://${s3BasePath}</arg>
      </distcp>
      <ok to="end"/>
      <error to="report_failure"/>
   </action>
```

And with credentials stored in a file in HDFS:

```
<action name="distcp">
    <distcp xmlns="uri:oozie:distcp-action:0.2">
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>hadoop.security.credential.provider.path</name>
                <value>${credentialsProviderPath}</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
        <arg>hdfs:${hdfsBaseDir}/data</arg>
        <arg>s3a://${s3BasePath}</arg>
    </distcp>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="report_failure"/>
</action>
```

One of the nice things is that the distcp-action is basically the CLI command `$> hadoop distcp <to> <from>` executed from java, which makes it easy to develop and debug by issuing the command on the command line.

Oozie is a nice tool for these type of exercises. E.g say you want to deploy it and let it run and that it can take a from some hours to a day to finish. It can prepare the environment, e.g check if destination exist or create folders etc. If it fails for some reason then Oozie can restart the whole execution or just some steps. And in the event of failure it sends mail etc.